# Progres bar с контрольными точками

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5, jquery-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой вопрос: кто работал с такими прогрес барами с ползунками и контрольными точками?
Столкнулся первым раз, нашел плагин, оказался корявым, игрался со спрайтами, в итоге 2 дня времени потерянно, кто-то сталкивался с таким?
Делал обычные через CSS и JS, но заказчику нужно чтоб можно было тягать ползунок и нажимать на сам прогресс бар
Буду очень благодарен любому совету)

Comment: так посмотрите как написано в плагине и модернизируйте под себя

Comment: посмотрите данный плагин - https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider